# error androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my android application it crashes and display this message, and I added the activity in androidmanifest but same error !!

```
11-16 08:56:00.077: E/AndroidRuntime(622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 08:56:00.077: E/AndroidRuntime(622): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.upnpexample/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

EDITED 
Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.upnpexample"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"></uses-      permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
 <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".UpnpControlApplication">
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BrowseActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BrowseServerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <service android:name=".BrowserUpnpService"></service>
    <activity android:label="@string/list_player" android:name=".EPGview"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/list_player" android:name=".Playsimplevideo"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/list_player" android:name=".Streaming"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/list_player" android:name=".LazyAdapter"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/list_player" android:name=".CustomizedListView"/>
</application>
```

**EDIT 2**

I put them in the same package and now it displays this errors

```
11-16 09:21:18.076: D/AndroidRuntime(710): Shutting down VM
11-16 09:21:18.076: W/dalvikvm(710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-16 09:21:18.086: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 09:21:18.086: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.upnpexample/com.upnpexample.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

i put them in the same package and now it displays this errors

```
11-16 09:21:18.076: D/AndroidRuntime(710): Shutting down VM
11-16 09:21:18.076: W/dalvikvm(710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-16 09:21:18.086: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 09:21:18.086: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.upnpexample/com.upnpexample.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: What about posting your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: `have you declared this activity CustomizedListView in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: clean and rebuild your code.

Comment: did u import any other project in ur project...becoz ur both packages are seem different com.upnpexample/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView check your packages hierarchy

Comment: yes i added a package to my project !! may be that's why ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the package in class CustomizedListView from:

```
package com.example.androidhive;
```

to:

```
package com.upnpexample;
```